# Resize Bitmap to 512x512 Without changing original aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a created bitmaps. Sizes are not specific.  Sometimes 120x60 , 129x800 , 851x784. Its not have a specific value... I want to make these bitmaps resizing to 512x512 always but without changing original images aspect ratio. And without cropping. New image must have canvas 512x512 and original image must be center without any cropping.

I was resizing my bitmaps with this function but it makes images really bad because image fitting X and Y . I don't want image to fit x and y on same time fits one of it and keeps its aspect ratio.

From https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/ :

```
 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

What I have;

[image]

What I want;

[image]

Comment: So you want to add a padding. In your example, right and left padding. When the original image is wider than it is tall, you'd add top and bottom padding.

Comment: @J.A.P obviously Mahir is talking about pixel aspect ratio, not image aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm want to fit my original image to 512x512 empty bitmap as centered and without any crop simply you can understand from images that I add to questions guys. Thanks again.

Comment: No it's not possible tecnichly. 1 pixel line on center :)

Comment: What you need is a padding. The minimum of scaleWidth and scaleHeight is your streching factor and calculate how much space is left and use it for your padding to center you bitmap into another one. See here
https://adilatwork.blogspot.com/2012/10/android-how-to-add-padding-or-border-to.html

Comment: Thanks guys for all comments. @Poohl 's answer solved my question. You can find the perfect output on comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you're really close. I can't test this right now, but basically what needs to be changed is

1) You need to apply the same scale to both X and Y, so you need to pick the smaller one (try the bigger one if that doesn't work).

```
matrix.postScale(Math.min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight), Math.min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight));
```

2) The result will be a bitmap  where at least one side is 512px large, the other one will be smaller. So you need to add the padding to fit that side to 512px (equally left and right/top and bottom for centering). In order to do so, you need to create an new bitmap of the desired size:

```
Bitmap outputimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(512,512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

3) and lastly depending on what side of the `resizedBitmap`  is 512px you need to draw `resizedBitmap` to the correct position in `outputImage`

```
Canvas can = new Canvas(outputimage);
can.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, (512 - resizedBitmap.getWidth()) / 2, (512 - resizedBitmap.getHeight()) / 2, null);
```

Note here, that `512 - resizedBitmap.getWidth()` results in `0` and therefor no padding at the side with correct size.

4) Now return `outputImage`

Comment: You are the king. Thats solved... I'm really thankfull. Here is the neww and final output :) http://prntscr.com/lu8gz9  You are really the best. I was working to fix it for more than 12 hours.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for marking my answer as solution.

Comment: @user8652379 Can you share the final code or edit this answer with final code 


user8652379

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplification in Kotlin that does both the scale and the translation with the matrix, skipping the intermediate bitmap.

Note that it also sets the background color to white for new pixels, which I needed for my image pipeline. Feel free to remove that if you don't need it.

```
fun resizedBitmapWithPadding(bitmap: Bitmap, newWidth: Int, newHeight: Int) : Bitmap {
    val scale = min(newWidth.toFloat() / bitmap.width, newHeight.toFloat() / bitmap.height)
    val scaledWidth = scale * bitmap.width
    val scaledHeight = scale * bitmap.height

    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale)
    matrix.postTranslate(
        (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2f,
        (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2f
    )

    val outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, bitmap.config)
    outputBitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE)
    
    Canvas(outputBitmap).drawBitmap(
        bitmap,
        matrix,
        null
    )

    return outputBitmap
}
```